# Merge two singly linked lists by getting 2 elements from each in Java

Tags: java, list

I need to output SLL (Singly linked list) that is result of merging two others in this way:

List1 = 5 6 7

List2 = 1 2 3 4

OutputList = **5 6** 1 2 **7** 3 4

or

List1 = 5 6 0 2 3 3

List2 = 2 4 5 2

OutputList = **5 6** 2 4 **0 2** 5 2 **3 3**

Either i am getting NullPointerException when asigning the succesor of the node, or i am stuck into while loop. Can you please help me?

Here is what I've done so far:

```
public SLL < E > specialJoin(SLL < E > list1, SLL < E > list2) {
    SLL result = new SLL();
    SLLNode temp1 = list1.first;
    SLLNode temp2 = list2.first;

    while (temp1 != null && temp2 != null) { // if there are still nodes in the lists
        result.insertLast(temp1.element); // first insert the first element
        if (temp1.succ != null) { // then check if there is still something
            result.insertLast(temp1.succ.element); // and add the second element
            temp1 = temp1.succ.succ; // at the end the next node will be the node after the succ of  the temporary element
        }

        rezultat.insertLast(temp2.element); // the same for the seconod list
        if (temp2.succ != null) {
            result.insertLast(temp2.succ.element);
            temp2 = temp2.succ.succ;
        }
    }
    // if there are still nodes in on of the lists we are apending them
    while (temp1 != null) {
        result.insertLast(temp1.element);
        temp1 = temp1.succ;
    }
    while (temp2 != null) {
        result.insertLast(temp2.element);
        temp2 = temp2.succ;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: are you getting NPE or is it going to Infinite loop? Your code is bit off, it will go to infinite loop when there are odd number of elements in both lists.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one thing you are missing in the first while loop when reaching the end of either of the lists :

```
    while(temp1 != null && temp2 != null){ // if there are still nodes in the lists
        result.insertLast(temp1.element); // first insert the first element
        if(temp1.succ != null){ // then check if there is still something
            result.insertLast(temp1.succ.element); // and add the second element
            temp1= temp1.succ.succ; // at the end the next node will be the node after the succ of  the temporary element
        } else { // added
            temp1= temp1.succ; // which is the same as temp1=null;
        }

        rezultat.insertLast(temp2.element); // the same for the seconod list
        if(temp2.succ != null){
            result.insertLast(temp2.succ.element);
            temp2 = temp2.succ.succ;
        } else { // added
            temp2 = temp2.succ; // which is the same as temp2=null;
        }
    }
```

Those added else clauses take care of the case when there's only one node left in one of the lists. Without them you may get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Doesn't work. Still getting  java.lang.NullPointerException on this line:
result.insertLast(temp1.succ.element); // and add the second element

Comment: @MinderMondo But you only call `result.insertLast(temp1.succ.element)` after checking that `temp1.succ != null`. It doesn't make sense. Perhaps you should include the code of `insertLast`.